# Relation between Ricci scalar and induced Ricci scalar?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature, event-horizon

Let's suppose we have some general, Lorentzian, $d$-dimensional spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ with associated metric $g$ (e.g., a black hole solution). Now let's suppose I consider some codimension-2 hypersurface $\mathcal{H}$ (the example of interest to me is the event horizon of a black hole) with induced metric $\gamma$ and unit binormal $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$. Is there, in general, a way to relate the induced Ricci scalar $\mathcal{R}[\gamma]$ on the hypersurface $\mathcal{H}$ to the full Ricci scalar $R[g]$ of the full spacetime $\mathcal{M}$? Obviously, for a particular example, one could always go and compute them and compare, but I'm curious if there is a more general relation.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for an extension of the codimension-$1$ result that is often presented when discussing the Gauss–Codazzi equations, e.g., [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Mean_curvature). They do point out that the relation is not going to be as nice for higher codimensions. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a reference where the computation might have been performed.